# css mobile fixed positioning

Tags: mobile, scroll, css-position

I have went all over the web to find a solution for this one ...

i want to create a fixed bottom menu for my web application,
As i learned the support is not cross platform and each device and browser presents a different obstacle,

I have placed an element with

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
left:0;
```

problem : it is very buggy on some browsers (pops to place after the scroll ends , stays on the center of the screen, etc ' ...)

is there a good solution for this issue , or should i give it a rest :-) ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cross-platform solution for this, mainly because many devices still do not support touch events, that's why iScroll fails on WindwsPhone for instance. I predict native `position: fixed;` won't be implemented for at least one year (even iOS did it recently, other mobile browsers are way behind; we can expect WP8 with IE10 will support it and some other browsers, but that is not enough). I suggest you keep your toolbar at bottom and keep you page height small enough so people do not have to scroll down a lot - your app will look same on all mobile platforms.